# Configuring Symfony DoctrineCouchDBBundle

Tags: php, symfony-2.4

I'm new to Symfony 2 and having difficulty setting up Doctrine.  I'm getting the following error when I try to persist my model: The class 'Foo' was not found in the chain configured namespaces.

I have a bootstrap file which requires the Composer autoloader and registers this loader with the AnnotationRegistry

```
use Doctrine\Common\Annotations\AnnotationRegistry;
$loader = require "vendor/autoload.php";
AnnotationRegistry::registerLoader(array($loader, "loadClass"));
```

I have CouchDB configured in the config.yml

```
doctrine_couch_db:
  client:
    connections:
      default:
        dbname: foo
        host: data.foo
        port: 5984
  odm:
    document_managers:
      default:
        connection: default
```

My model is tagged with annotations

```
use Doctrine\ODM\CouchDB\Mapping\Annotations as ODM;

/**
 * Model object for foo data.
 * @ODM\Document
 */
class Foo {
    ...
}
```

I've got a ContainerAwareCommand which I use to get a Doctrine ObjectManager

```
$dm = $this->getContainer()->get("doctrine_couchdb.odm.default_document_manager");
```

But when I try to persist

```
$dm->persist(new Foo());
```

I get an error

```
The class 'Foo' was not found in the chain configured namespaces
```

edit: upon further investigation, the MappingDriverChain is empty.  There is no defaultDriver and no values in the drivers array.  I don't know how this gets populated, but it seems like this is the root problem.

Answer (score 0):

Basically it took me 2 hours to get the problem solved by myself.
You have to put your entities not into the entity folder but into the CouchDocument folder for autoload.

Second i needed to add my bundle to the manager configuration as follows:

```
doctrine_couch_db:
  client:
    dbname: sddb
  odm:
    document_managers:
      default:
        mappings:
          SDDBBundle:
            type: annotation
        auto_mapping: true
```

Namespace for a document looks like:

```
namespace SDDB\SDDBBundle\CouchDocument;
```

sometimes the documentation is no the best... cause no one tells you this in the fast and dirty start example